# What to do with corrected wrongly classified random forest predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have trained a multi-class Random Forest model and So now if the model predicts something wrong we manually correct it, SO the thing is What can we do to with that corrected label and make the predictions better.

Thoughts:

1. Can't retrain the model again and again.(Trained on 0.7 million rows so it might treat the new data as noise)
2. Can not train small models of RF as they will also create a mess
3. Random FOrest works better then NN, So not thinking to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

- What do you mean by "manually correct" - *i.e.* there may be various different points in the decision trees that were executed leading to a wrong prediction, not to mention the numerous decision trees used to get your final prediction.
- I think there is some misunderstanding in your first point.  Unless the distribution is non-stationary (in which case your trained model is of diminished value to begin with), the new data is treated is treated as "noise" in the sense that including it in the final model is unlikely to change future predictions all that much.  As far as I can tell this is how it should be, without specifying other factors like a changing distribution, etc.  That is, if future data you want to predict will look a lot more like the data you failed to predict correctly, then you would indeed want to upweight the importance of classifying this sample in your new model.

Anyway, it sounds like you're describing an [online learning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)(you want a model that updates itself in response to streaming data).  You can find some general ideas just searching for online random forests, for example:

- [Online random forests] (http://www.ymer.org/amir/research/online-random-forests/) and [online multiclass lpboost] (https://github.com/amirsaffari/online-multiclass-lpboost) describe a general framework akin to what you may have in mind: the input to the model is a stream of new observations; the forest learns on this new data by dropping those trees which perform poorly and eventually growing new trees that include the new data.
- The general idea described here is used in a number of boosting algorithms (for example, [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) aggregates an ensemble of "weak learners", for example individual decision trees grown on different + incomplete subsets of data, into a better whole by training subsequent weak learners specifically on formerly misclassified instances.  The idea here is that those instances where your current model is wrong are the most informative for future performance improvements.
- I don't know the specific details of how the linked implementations accomplish this, though the idea is inline with what you might expect.

You might try these, or other such algorithms you find from searching around.

That all said, I suspect something like the online random forest algorithm is relatively good when old data becomes obsolete over time.  If it doesn't -- i.e. if your future data and early data are pulled from the same distribution -- it's not obvious to me that successively retraining your model (by which I mean the random forest itself and any cross validation / model selection procedures you might have to transform forest predictions into a final assignment) data on the whole batch of examples you have is a bad idea, modulo data in a very high dimensional feature space, or really quickly incoming data.

Comment: a reviewer will go through the output and will correct if the output is wrong.

Comment: How is that prediction?